# Parameterizing monotonic functions

Tags: functions, beta-function, monotone-functions

I am trying to design a function $f_{\alpha} : \left[0,1\right] \rightarrow [0,+\inf)$ that looks like the following:

[image]

It should have the following properties:

- Its **integral** should be 1 for any value of $\alpha$.
- When $\alpha<0$ it should be monotonically decreasing
- When $\alpha=0$ it should be be be flat.
- When $\alpha>0$ it should be monotonically increasing.
- The greater $|\alpha|$ is, "the more monotonic" the function can be (not sure if there is a better way to define this).
- It should be  *easy* to compute, for any value of $\alpha$ and $x$ (i.e. in terms of algorithmic complexity).
- Ideally these effects should be visible for $\alpha$ in the range $(-1,1)$. If helpful we can make sure the function is only defined for $\alpha \in (-1, 1)$.

I know there is obviously an infinite number of functions that can fit this profile, but I am hoping to find something algebraically simple that fits the above description.

---

Some thoughts:

- The closest that comes to mind is perhaps some sub-family of the [Beta pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). Is there an easy to restrict $(\alpha, \beta)$ to produce these shapes with a new single parameter, e.g. $\gamma$?

Comment: If $\alpha >> 0$ the function will not vanish at infinity and thus not have integral $1$.

Comment: Thanks @menag I have updated the description to define the support of $\alpha \in \left(-1, 1\right)$.

Comment: Any function may be modified to fit the integral property by adding a constant that depends on alpha $c(\alpha)$.

Comment: How about $f_\alpha (x) =\alpha e^{\alpha x}/(e^\alpha - 1)$ for $\alpha\not=0$, and $f_0(x) =1$? Or do you want $f_\alpha$ to have a vertical asymptote when $|\alpha|$ is large?

Comment: @JohnDawkins No need for a vertical asymptote, although that would be great.

Comment: How about $(1/\alpha )x^\alpha$?

Comment: @amcerbu that looks great, does it work property-wise?

Comment: The integral works out for any $\alpha > 0$. You have to do a bit of legwork to get it to work for $\alpha < 0$, because $\int_0^1 1/x^n \, dx$ doesn't converge in general for $n > 1$.

Comment: Ah, sorry – it should be $(\alpha+1) x^\alpha$ – then it works for $\alpha > -1$.